# Имеется проблема с PIP

Tags: python, django, pip, python-2.7

У меня имеется проблема с менеджером пакетов pip , я использую операционную систему MacOS и при проверке версии не зависимо от команды pip или pip3 в терминале выдаётся сообщение о том что используется python2.7 . [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
До этого всё работало нормально , проблемы начались после создания virtualenv , когда при установке на этот виртуальный энвайрмент я заметил что он устанавливает все пакеты под python2.7.

Comment: Если вы пишите backend, посмотрите docker

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov а при чёи тут докер?

Comment: Потому что в виртуальном окружении питон версии 2.7.

Comment: @Sanjar Dauletov, это универсальное решение вопросов "что-то не запускается под чем-то" и "версии чего-то не совпадают"

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -m venv my_venv
source my_venv/bin/activate
```